# Generation of sine waves within the audible range using a DAC

Tags: arduino, oscillator, dac

I am trying to generate up to 20 khz sine wave with the [TLC5615](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/Datasheets/TLC5615.pdf) DAC but have only been able to obtain a maximum of 100 hz. I am using a 20 MHZ atmega328 MCU to transfer the required 16 bits (2 padding, 10 bit precision, 4 dummy bits) and also to act as the software defined clock for the device. In order to generate the sine wave I have a lookup table with ~64 values in order to obtain a decent sine wave.

Here is all of the code

```
int sine[] = {0x7fc ,0x868 ,0x8d4 ,0x93c ,0x9a8 ,0xa10 ,0xa78 ,0xadc 
,0xb3c ,0xba0 ,0xbfc ,0xc58 ,0xcb0 ,0xd04 ,0xd58 ,0xda4 ,0xdf0 ,0xe34 ,0xe74 
,0xeb0 ,0xee8 ,0xf1c ,0xf4c ,0xf74 ,0xf98 ,0xfb8 ,0xfd0 ,0xfe4 ,0xff0 ,0xff8 
,0xffc ,0xff8 ,0xff0 ,0xfe4 ,0xfd0 ,0xfb8 ,0xf98 ,0xf74 ,0xf4c ,0xf1c ,0xee8 
,0xeb0 ,0xe74 ,0xe34 ,0xdf0 ,0xda4 ,0xd58 ,0xd04 ,0xcb0 ,0xc58 ,0xbfc ,0xba0 
,0xb3c ,0xadc ,0xa78 ,0xa10 ,0x9a8 ,0x93c ,0x8d4 ,0x868 ,0x7fc ,0x794 ,0x728 
,0x6bc ,0x654 ,0x5ec ,0x584 ,0x520 ,0x4bc ,0x45c ,0x400 ,0x3a4 ,0x34c ,0x2f4 
,0x2a4 ,0x258 ,0x20c ,0x1c8 ,0x188 ,0x148 ,0x110 ,0xe0 ,0xb0 ,0x88 ,0x64 ,0x44 
,0x2c ,0x18 ,0xc ,0x0 ,0x0 ,0x0 ,0xc ,0x18 ,0x2c ,0x44 ,0x64 ,0x88 ,0xb0 ,0xe0 
,0x110 ,0x148 ,0x188 ,0x1c8 ,0x20c ,0x258 ,0x2a4 ,0x2f4 ,0x34c ,0x3a4 ,0x400 
,0x45c ,0x4bc ,0x520 ,0x584 ,0x5ec ,0x654 ,0x6bc ,0x728 ,0x794};

#define samples 120

#define intL 16

void setup(){

  pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}


int j = 0;
int k = intL-1;

unsigned int cval = 0;
int current = 0;

byte currentBit = 0;

void loop(){

  PORTB = B00000000;

   cval = sine[j];

  while(k != 0)
  {
    currentBit = (cval >> k) & 1;

    if(currentBit)
    {
      PORTB = B00010000;
      PORTB = B00110000;
      PORTB = B00010000;
    }
    else
    {
      PORTB = B00100000;
      PORTB = B00000000;
    }



      k--;
  }

   PORTB = B00001000;

  k=intL-1;

  j++;

  if(j == samples)
  {
    j = 0;
  }
}
```

Within the loop method I maintain a counter of the current value of the wave. I also maintain a counter of the current bit that needs to be written and in order to write in LSb order, that counter has to count backwards. Then I shift the word by that specified amount. After I know the value, I trigger the clock, write the value and set the clock once more. After the word has been shifted into the DAC you have to drive Chip Select input high.

I am afraid this is about performant as it could get using the lookup method, so I would like to know if there are any alternatives or what I need in order to achieve ~20 khz frequencies.

Comment: Are you a dog or a bat because you consider 20kHz to be in the audible range?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get 20kHz signals, you need to do at least 3 things.

The first is get 50ks/s or more transferred to your DAC. That means running the SPI clock at around 1MHz or more. Reading between the lines, the DAC should be able to accept at least 10MHz SPI clock. The challenge is to find the MCU library that can transmit SPI at 1MHz.

The second is to generate sine samples at the right rate. Having saved 64 samples of a sine wave in your table, you do not need to step through them one at a time, you can do 2 steps at a time, or more. In fact if you were generating a 20kHz signal at 50kHz sampling rate, you would be stepping 0.4 of a circle = 144 degrees = about 25 steps of a 64 entry table.

For a table-less way of doing it, look up CORDIC. You should find a 20MHz atmega328 is fast enough to do that.

The third thing is to design and build an anti-alias filter to go after your DAC, which must pass the fmax of 20kHz, and block all frequencies from (sampling_rate - fmax) upwards. With a 50kHz sample rate, that's pass 20kHz, block 30kHz and up. You can ease the steepness requirement of the filter by increasing the sample rate. At 100kHz, you would only need to block frequencies above 80kHz, a much easier filter to build.

Some audio DACs oversample within the DAC with digital filters to make things much much easier. The DAC you have quoted doesn't do this.

Comment: Actually 40 ks/s will do -- see [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency).

Comment: The analog filtering on the output is also important if you want the wave to actually look like a sinewave when you're close to the Nyquist frequency.

Comment: You probably want to go a little over the Nyquist frequency for your sampling. Running at the literally minimum possible frequency means that any jitter or skew making the clock seem faster than 20KHz would throw off the sampling.

Comment: Absolutely.  Nyquist is a mathematical ideal value, but it's not necessarily easy to reconstruct a nyquist-sampled sine wave.  Note that 1 20kHz sine wave sampled from the 1rst zero crossing at 40kHz will give you every zero-crossing, not a sine wave!

Comment: which is why I suggested 50k, not 40k.

Comment: @jbord39 You are right, that is why CD's are said to span 20 Hz to 22 kHz, but have a sample rate of 44.1 ks/s, not 44 ks/s.  So the OP needs to output at least 40.1 ks/s not 40 ks/s as I earlier stated.  The standard CD rate of 44.1 ks/s might be a good compromise between the minimum and Neil's suggestion of 50 ks/s.

Comment: The OP needs to be well over 2*max, otherwise he can't design a practical anti alias filter. 44.1kHz CD sample rate for 20kHz fmax is pushing it somewhat, that's why there's another 'standard' audio rate of 48kHz, which is rather easier to apply.

Comment: Why push it? The arduino could easily go well above fmax in this case, right?